# Is it possible to set one cell's formula to fire before another?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

**Context:** I have a pretty massive GoogleSheets file - tons of cells, a good amount of now() functions, so anytime there is a change, a long recalculation starts and the sheet loads for a ~2 minutes.

**Goal:** I want to hide the results of one cell until the calculation has completed.

Anyway to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

use `IF` statement. for example:

cell A1:

```
=5*3
```

cell B1:

```
=IF(A1<>""; 61*2; )
```

cell C1:

```
=IF(B1<>""; SUM(55; 44); )
```

`SUM(55; 44)` will be calculated only after  B1 gets calculated and B1 is dependent on A1, eg every formula will start with the end of the previous one instead of all firing at once